# What’s an "IHV"?

Tags: terminology

I have seen several questions here referencing the “IHVs,” e.g. [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/155120/76339), without defining the abbreviation.

A Google search offers “Inter-Human Virology,” and, a few links down, a Wikipedia disambiguation page that includes “[independent hardware vendor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_hardware_vendor),” which certainly *seems* more pertinent to the contexts in which I’ve seen “IHV” here, but I’m not certain about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, IHV in this context means **Independent Hardware Vendor**. In the linked answer it refers mainly to AMD and NVidia.

Comment: No worries; we’ve all been there with basic questions, it can be hard to keep perspective when you have a lot of expertise, and after all, this site *is* primarily aimed at experts. I appreciate the gracious apology.

Comment: Actually, it's not supposed to be primarily aimed at experts. It's just that experts are more likely to know _how to ask_ their questions. So it might seem that way, but it's not supposed to be.

Comment: @KRyan This site is aimed at having experts share their knowledge. It's not aimed at experts being the askers. However, in the future, you're likely to get better help if you spend more time searching, trying out different keywords, etc.. Not only will your questions be more specific and, therefore more answerable, but you'll also learn how to find the answers yourself, which will save you a _lot_ of time, compared to writing up a decent question and asking it.

Comment: @Almo I am very familiar with the Stack Exchange model and I know very well how much expertise is or isn’t expected. I did qualify it as *primarily*. Yes, new users are welcome, of course, but experts are catered to. That’s built into the very system.

Comment: @NicHartley Short of mind-reading, or, ya know, asking, it is very unlikely that I could have confirmed to my satisfaction that what I found with my search was actually what was being meant by users here. Moreover, since another aspect of the Stack Exchange model is to create a solid repository of knowledge, if this is a common term (and it clearly is, seeing as it was used here) in this field, it’s reasonably appropriate for this site to include a definition of it. If an answer here leads me to another question, searching *here* (which I did) should get me my answer. And now it would.

Comment: @LukeG: I don't understand what "IHV" has to do with immediate mode OpenGL. It's completely independent of this.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was referring to the context of the answer where the asker encountered this term.